# Visual C++ with included OpenCV 2.4.9 compile error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to write a code to display a video from camera on a windows form in Visual Studio 2010 environment. Here below is my code:

```
#pragma once

#include <opencv\cv.h>

#include <opencv\highgui.h>

extern CvCapture* cam;
extern IplImage* image,*image_copy;
static CvMemStorage* storage = 0;
static CvHaarClassifierCascade* cascade = 0;
extern const char* cascade_name;

private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


         cam=cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
         image=cvQueryFrame(cam);
         if ((videoBox->Image==nullptr))
         {
             Bitmap^img1=gcnew Bitmap(videoBox->Width,videoBox->Height);
             videoBox->Image=img1;
         }
         cascade=(CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad(cascade_name,0,0,0);
         storage=cvCreateMemStorage(0);
         if(cam)
         {
             {
                 if(!image_copy)
                     image_copy=cvCreateImage(cvSize(image->width,image->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U,image->nChannels);
                 if(image->origin==IPL_ORIGIN_TL)
                     cvCopy(image,image_copy,0);
                 else cvFlip(image,image_copy,0);
                 //khai bao mang mau
                     static CvScalar colors[] = 
                     {
                         {{0,0,255}},//red
                         {{0,128,255}},//orange
                         {{0,255,255}},//cyan
                         {{0,255,0}},//green
                         {{255,128,0}},//blue
                         {{255,255,0}},//yellow
                         {{255,0,0}},//blue+
                         {{255,0,255}}//pink
                     };

                     double scale = 1.3;
                     IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvSize(image_copy->width,image_copy->height), 8, 1 );
                     IplImage* small_img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( cvRound (image_copy->width/scale),cvRound (image_copy->height/scale)),8,1);
                     //int i;
                     cvCvtColor( image_copy, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
                     cvResize( gray, small_img, CV_INTER_LINEAR );
                     cvEqualizeHist( small_img, small_img );
                     cvClearMemStorage( storage );

                 Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(videoBox->Image);

                 Bitmap^ anh2 = gcnew Bitmap(image_copy->width,image_copy->height,image_copy->widthStep,System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb, IntPtr(image_copy->imageData));

                 g->DrawImage(anh2, (videoBox->Width-image_copy->width)/2, (videoBox->Height-image_copy->height)/2);
                 videoBox->Refresh();
                 delete(g);
             }
         }
     }
```

};
}

At first, .NET Framework 4.5.1 was installed on my computer. But when I compiled the code, I received this error:

"LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt"

I looked for solution and found that Visual Studio 2010 just works with .NET Framework 4. I uninstalled version 4.5.1 and installed version 4. But after that, I received this error:

```
1>Manual_Mode.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A0007F1) "extern "C" void __cdecl cvClearMemStorage(struct CvMemStorage *)" (?cvClearMemStorage@@$$J0YAXPAUCvMemStorage@@@Z)
1>Control_Interface.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0007FF) "extern "C" void __cdecl cvClearMemStorage(struct CvMemStorage *)" (?cvClearMemStorage@@$$J0YAXPAUCvMemStorage@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __clrcall Control_Interface::Manual_Mode::timer1_Tick(class System::Object ^,class System::EventArgs ^)" (?timer1_Tick@Manual_Mode@Control_Interface@@$$FA$AAMXP$AAVObject@System@@P$AAVEventArgs@4@@Z)
1>Control_Interface.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cv::SparseMat::addref(void)" (?addref@SparseMat@cv@@$$FQAEXXZ)
1>Manual_Mode.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@$$FYAHPAHH@Z)
1>C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Control_Interface\Debug\Control_Interface.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 51 unresolved externals
```

Can you please tell me how to deal with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "with included OpenCV 2.4.9?" As far as I know OpenCV is not installed with Visual Studio 2010. It is an add on component that you must download from http://opencv.org/?

Comment: please *don't* use opencv's deprecated c-api, but the c++ api(cv:Mat) instead !

Comment: why all those extern  modifiers ? are those variables defined elsewhere or not ? (if not, this is your linker error)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reduce your code further to the bare minimum, which you should do in the future before asking here. Anyhow, I guess from a short view that the problem is that your "extern" tells the compiler that there is an object of the given type and name somewhere, but you have to make sure it really exists. What you probably want is to tell the compiler to create such an object (note that a pointer is an object, according to the C++ object model), which you achieve by dropping the "extern".

If, in the future, you get linker errors due to multiply defined symbols, do the opposite: Only leave a single place without extern, all others with extern.

Comment: I have removed the "extern" and re-declared as below:

namespace{
CvCapture* cam=0;
IplImage* image,*image_copy=0;
const char* cascade_name ="haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml";}

However, I still get the same errors. Can you please show me how to correct these errors? Many thanks to you.